# Caching and Compressing of dynamically generated javascript

Tags: php

I am using php for generating javascript dynamically based on different conditions. I want browser to be able to cache it for specific amount of time.

I am using the following code for caching, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript; charset: UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
$offset = 60 * 60 ;
$ExpStr = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
header($ExpStr);
```

Also, The js file is quite big, ~290 KBs, So I want to send it compressed to the browser to reduce download time. any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the **Expires** header name, So the line

```
$ExpStr = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
```

Should be

```
$ExpStr = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";

// output your js file here
```

And for compressing the output, uncomment ( or add if not exists) the following line in PHP.ini. to deflate or compress the output. Don't forget to restart the server after modifying PHP.ini

```
output_handler = ob_gzhandler
```

Comment: And if he hasn't got access to the php.ini he could still use `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` to compress all output.

Comment: @louis-h Thanks for another way, though fortunately I have access to the php.ini file.